# "Predisposed to" + gerund or infinitive?

Tags: gerund-vs-infinitive

My own logic and basic grammar rules would say gerund:
*He is predisposed to plagiarizing.*

Because I would also say:
*He is predisposed to plagiarism.*

But Google tells me that:
*He is predisposed to plagiarize.*

is just as common. I have also seen, e.g.:
*He has a predisposition to plagiarize.*

I think I'm right and they're wrong. What do you think?

Comment: Hello, Chuckk. What research have you done? ELU requires reasonable research to be **shown**.   [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/predispose) seems happy with either _ing_-form or infinitive after 'predisposed to', giving the examples  _Some people seem predisposed to accept stories about mysteries or the inexplicable._
Christianity Today (2000) //  
I don't think he would be a judgmental person condemning individuals for actions that they may be genetically predisposed to taking.
Times, Sunday ...

Comment: Times (2008) (licensing 'They may be genetically predisposed to taking such actions.')

Comment: I confess I had only searched for sentences using the phrase, after seeing that no dictionary definitions I could find clarified this point.

Answer (score 1):

All those constructions, and some more besides, are completely acceptable and standard.

**The verb form**
 (*predisposed to* or *predispose* [someone or something] *to*)

The OED has all three possibilities among the examples it lists:

**Infinitival:**
          *Tristy was p̲r̲e̲d̲i̲s̲p̲o̲s̲e̲d̲ ̲t̲o̲ ̲b̲e̲l̲i̲e̲v̲e̲ that Van Gogh must have been a determined and inveterate ‘faker’.*

**Gerund:**
          *We have not even a word in English for the complex of psychological elements which p̲r̲e̲d̲i̲s̲p̲o̲s̲e̲s̲ ̲u̲s̲ ̲t̲o̲ ̲f̲o̲r̲g̲e̲t̲t̲i̲n̲g̲.*

**Noun phrase (NP):**
          *New Yorkers..are always p̲r̲e̲d̲i̲s̲p̲o̲s̲e̲d̲ ̲t̲o̲ ̲d̲r̲a̲m̲a̲-̲q̲u̲e̲e̲n̲ ̲s̲e̲l̲f̲-̲i̲m̲p̲o̲r̲t̲a̲n̲c̲e̲.*

**The noun form**
 
(*predisposition to*)

The OED has the following:

**NP:**
          *One of the few indicators of a possible p̲r̲e̲d̲i̲s̲p̲o̲s̲i̲t̲i̲o̲n̲ ̲t̲o̲ ̲m̲e̲n̲t̲a̲l̲ ̲i̲l̲l̲n̲e̲s̲s̲ in a given individual is a positive family history of such illness.*

**Infinitival:**
          *There was a strong p̲r̲e̲d̲i̲s̲p̲o̲s̲i̲t̲i̲o̲n̲ ̲t̲o̲ ̲b̲e̲l̲i̲e̲v̲e̲ that China's culture..was dynamic and changing in nature.*

But in published literature (i.e. if one searches google books for the underlined phrase, below), one can easily find

**Gerund:**
          *A psychological p̲r̲e̲d̲i̲s̲p̲o̲s̲i̲t̲i̲o̲n̲ ̲t̲o̲ ̲b̲e̲l̲i̲e̲v̲i̲n̲g̲ in moralizing gods could then be favored by natural selection within groups.*
          *The p̲r̲e̲d̲i̲s̲p̲o̲s̲i̲t̲i̲o̲n̲ ̲t̲o̲ ̲f̲a̲l̲l̲i̲n̲g̲ ̲b̲a̲c̲k̲w̲a̲r̲d̲ may result from a smaller posterior than anterior base of support.*
          *If you adopt a dog with this type of genetic p̲r̲e̲d̲i̲s̲p̲o̲s̲i̲t̲i̲o̲n̲ ̲t̲o̲ ̲f̲i̲g̲h̲t̲i̲n̲g̲, you must...*

Comment: I can think of no other phrase that can accept both 'to' + infinitive and 'to' + gerund, but I guess that would be another question to ask.

Comment: @chuckk-hubbard *Lead* seems to be one... *It **led to winning** the match.* *His training and influence **led me to win** several championship title fights.* *And this is what I found, a path that **led me to victory**.* I'm pretty sure that if I stared a bit longer at [CGEL's](https://www.amazon.com/Cambridge-Grammar-English-Language/dp/0521431468) list of catentaive verbs (in particular of class 3Ai), I could probably find at least one or two more.

Comment: One question that puzzles me is why the verb *predispose* doesn't appear on any comprehensive list of English catenative verbs I know of (OK, I know just two—the one in CGEL and [this one](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_catenative_verbs)—but still).

Comment: ... Yes; I've just had to add it to mine. 320 now. Verbs accepting complex catenations with both _ing_-forms and to-infinitives include _bear, countenance, depend on, discover, like, love, get, hate, have, see, stand, take,_ and _want_. With _imagine_, the following verb probably needs to be 'to be' as a to-infinitive. . With _help_ (I can't help John being clumsy / I help John to be tidy), the different catenations have different meanings (do anything about / aid).

Comment: @edwin-ashworth Oh wow! I hope you consider updating [this list](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_catenative_verbs) with yours!

Comment: @edwin-ashworth But in terms of *predispose* and *like*, it's not about accepting *-ing* form, but rather about accepting  ***to*** + *-ing* form (as well as *to*-infinitives). That's presumably rare. On the other hand, I doubt that the ability to accept *to* + *-ing* form has much to do with the verb being catenative (despite the fact that I don't have an example of a verb that can do it but is not catenative).

Comment: This is a different construction. He is predisposed to knitting // given to fishing // addicted to painting/chess // drawn to collecting stamps. The _ing_-forms here are more nouny in character. With _like_ in a complex catenation, the _ing_-form (there, the ACC-ing form) is nearer the verbal end of the continuum (I like John going to the opera).

Comment: @edwin-ashworth Yes, agreed. I was just addressing Chuckk Hubbard's comment, which was about verbs that accept both *to*-infinitive and *to* + *-ing*-forms, regardless of how unrelated these two constructions may be. I don't think either *given* or *addicted* accepts *to*-infinitives as complements. However, *draw* appears to: *I was drawn to try to write something*; *Three things drew me to try my hand at it anyway*. So that makes three verbs that I now know can do that: *predispose*, *lead*, and *draw*.

Comment: @edwin-ashworth On the other hand, *addict* seems to be an example of something that, just a few comments above, I said I didn't have: a verb that is not catenative, and yet accepts *to* + *-ing*-form as a complement. (The construction with *given* seems to be an idiom, since I don't think one can use its active form in the same way.)

Comment: You need to look up 'verb + preposition' colligations where the preposition is 'to'. I **introduced** her **to** dancing. // He never  **responds**   **to** tickling. / He never **admitted to** killing the dog. / She hasn't **adjusted to** having more free time. / She **resorted to** hiding her diary under the sofa. / They have not  **stooped to** using threats of violence. / They have **come to** using targeted advertising campaigns.

Comment: @edwin-ashworth Good point. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your first two samples, 'to' is a preposition meaning 'toward'.  In the latter two samples it is an infinitive marker.  All are grammatical, but 'toward' is more vague ("to[ward] [possibly?] plagiarizing" or "to[ward] [committing?] plagiarism").

Comment: Answers need to be supported by authoritative references, even when they are correct.

Comment: Well, I knew that about 'to', but some phrases use it as preposition and some as infinitive particle, and I wondered which works for 'predispose'. It appears it can do either.

Comment: The subject of catenative/control/raising verbs is not simple, but a passive superordinate verb is often followed by a to-infinitive.  'Bias' is a verb that comes close to the pattern for 'predispose', whereas 'expect' is quite different.  I recommend using 'toward' instead of 'to' for prepositional uses where the destination is not obtained -- "he moved to the left" vs "he tended toward the left".